# Ubuntu 18 Wifi won't connect, has worked before

Tags: wireless, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I installed Ubuntu 18 on new desktop computer on SSD with dualboot on Windows on other SSD. My home wifi worked perfectly fine until one day, where it would not connect anymore, out of nowhere.
I see the wireless network in the wifi list but can't connect to it, it loads indefinitely.
Same issue with ethernet connexion, so any solution requiring no downloads would be very much appreciated.
Also, when I boot on Windows, wifi and ethernet works fine.

Here are some classical commands outputs:

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

sudo lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   produit: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   fabriquant: Qualcomm Atheros
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
   nom logique: enp3s0
   version: 13
   numéro de série: d4:3d:7e:f3:24:67
   capacité: 1Gbit/s
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   ressources: irq:19 mémoire:f7200000-f723ffff portE/S:d000(taille=128)
  *-network
   description: Interface réseau sans fil
   produit: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:04:00.0
   nom logique: wlp4s0
   version: 01
   numéro de série: 18:31:bf:a4:53:bf
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   ressources: irq:29 portE/S:c000(taille=256) mémoire:f7100000-f7103fff
```

sudo lsmod (only interesting line)

```
rtl8821ae             233472  0
```

sudo nmcli device show wlp4s0 | grep IP4.DNS

```
nothing happens
```

ip address

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether d4:3d:7e:f3:24:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 18:31:bf:a4:53:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 2a01:cb05:88e4:e100:5132:49f4:7367:c3d5/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
   valid_lft 1800sec preferred_lft 600sec
inet6 2a01:cb05:88e4:e100:4fb8:453c:31b2:7919/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
   valid_lft 1800sec preferred_lft 600sec
inet6 fe80::b75f:a43e:44e9:3449/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I also tried to change /etc/network/interfaces and add this to the end of the file:

```
auto wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
wpa-essid myssid
wpa-psk mypassword
```

The result was that I could not see the wifi networks anymore and got a message on wireless network manager: "not supported" (translation)

The connexion seems to be stuck at stage 70: IP configuration

**Edit 1:**
I tried to boot from old kernel (Linux 4.15.0-34-generic instead of 0-36-generic) but I get the same issue.

**Edit 2:**
Tried to connect with ethernet cable, same issue of infinite loading and ethernet connexion works on windows boot

**Edit 3:**
Following command gives me an error:
sudo dhclient wlp4s0

```
dhclient: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Error 20
```

Do you have any idea why the wifi stopped working when in my opinion nothing changed on the computer or on the network?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved from the information of Edit 3.

I post the answer for those who might have the same issue.

I downloaded zlib1g package with another computer from https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/zlib1g-dev

Then installed on the not-working-wifi-computer with

```
sudo dpkg -i zlib1g-dev_1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

And then again

```
sudo dhclient wlp4s0
```

And everything came back to normal. No idea where this problem came from.